# Angular cookies and factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

How do I integrate Angular cookies with a factory?

I have a module:

```
angular.module('myModule')
  .factory('myWarehouse', myWarehouseFactory);

myWarehouseFactory.$inject = ['Workers', 'Food'];

function myWarehouseFactory( Workers, Food ) {

  return function() {
    Workers.atWork(true)
      .then(function() {

        var familiar = $cookies.get('Workers');

        $cookies.put(familiar, 'John');

        if ('John' == familiar) {
          // Do something
        }

      });
  };
}
```

The $cookies / ngCookies documentation only shows examples of use with a controller. Is this necessary in my case? Where do I inject $cookies, inside the module parenthesis, the factory, or the factory.$inject?

Comment: inject `$cookies` inside your controller

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will do it for you:

```
myWarehouseFactory.$inject = ['Workers', 'Food', '$cookies'];

function myWarehouseFactory( Workers, Food, $cookies ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
  angular.module('myModule',['ngCookies']) //injecting cookies module in app
    .factory('myWarehouse', myWarehouseFactory);

  myWarehouseFactory.$inject = ['Workers', 'Food','$cookies']; //injecting in factory

  function myWarehouseFactory( Workers, Food, $cookies ) {

    return function() {
      Workers.atWork(true)
        .then(function() {

          var familiar = $cookies.get('Workers');

          $cookies.put(familiar, 'John');

          if ('John' == familiar) {
            // Do something
          }

        });
    };
  }
```